# How do I insert the database's default for a column in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to insert a row into a Postgresql table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE launch_ids(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  launch_time TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT
    (now() at time zone 'utc')
);
```

My class looks like this:

```
class LaunchId(Base):
    """Launch ID table for runs"""
    __tablename__ = 'launch_ids'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    launch_time = Column(DateTime)
```

The `launch_time` should be managed by the database. I know it's possible to use `default=datetime.datetime.utcnow()`, but that uses the current time on the client. I know it's possible to use `default=func.now()`, but that means that if the database's definition of the default changes, then I need to change the default in two places.

Here is what I get when I try to insert a row in `launch_ids` without specifying a value:

```
l = LaunchId()
session.add(l)
session.commit()

IntegrityError: (psycopg2.IntegrityError) null value in column "launch_time" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, null).
 [SQL: 'INSERT INTO launch_ids (launch_time) VALUES (%(launch_time)s) RETURNING launch_ids.id'] [parameters: {'launch_time': None}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `FetchedValue`:

```
from sqlalchemy.schema import FetchedValue

class LaunchId(Base):
    ...
    launch_time = Column(DateTime, FetchedValue())
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify the `server_default` on the column like this:

```
class LaunchId(Base):
    """Launch ID table for runs"""
    __tablename__ = 'launch_ids'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    launch_time = Column(DateTime, nullable=False
                         server_default=text("(now() at time zone 'utc')"))
```

Then adding a new launch_id through the session will work. `server_default` works differently from `default` in that it is generated on the server side. Official SQLAlchemy documentation: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/defaults.html#server-side-defaults

By specifying `nullable=False`, this model also becomes a true reflection of the `CREATE TABLE` you specified, and thus can be generated through `Base.metadata.create_all` or using `alembic`.

Comment: I don't think that addresses the issue. It still uses the code specified in the Python file rather than the default defined in the table. I want to use whatever default is defined on the table in the database, not some hard-coded text in my Python code.